# How to handle json key herror

Tags: python, json

i explain my problem:
i have a JsonResponse from an API, that include parameter in the response if the book that i asked for is available, if it is not available i don't have some parameter, so how i can handle this, whitout stop my code with a Raise Key Error?

```
result = requests.get('https://api.rainforestapi.com/request',params)

jsonStringResult = json.dumps(result.json())
jsonResult = json.loads(jsonStringResult)
print(jsonResult['product']['title'])
autori = jsonResult['product']['authors']
for autore in autori:
    print(autore['name'])
print(jsonResult['product']['buybox_winner']['availability']['raw'])
print(jsonResult['product']['buybox_winner']['price']['raw'])
categorie = jsonResult['product']['categories']
for i in range(len(categorie)):
    if i == len(categorie)-1:
        print(categorie[i]['name'])
```

the problem is in the 'buybox_winner' beacuse when the book isn't avaialable for purchase, there isn't the buybox winner, so i have to handle two situation. Can you help me for the situation when the book isn't avaialable?

Comment: Instead of dumps/loads you can simply put `jsonResult =result.json()` You can use  e.g. `if ‘buybox_winner’ in jsonResult[‘product’]:` to test if the key is present. Or use `bb=jsonResult[‘product’].get(‘busybox’,None)` and then `if bb:` to continue access `bb[‘price’] etc. These are all normal dictionary methods, nothing specific to json, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get

Comment: For more details of `in` see section 6.10.2. Membership test operations here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: I would simply go for a try-catch block here

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to the comment but more appropriate and detailed.

```
something = jsonResult['product'].get('buybox_winner', {}).get('availability', {}).get('raw', None)
```

The get method, for dicts, attempts to access to the key provided and returns None ( by default ) if it does not exist, the second one parameter overrides the default value to return. So setting {} as second param let u keep using get method until the last one key u need to access.